# IO-manipulators as template parameters?

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to work with a class, let's call it a `stream_wrapper`.
It contains a value of (or a reference to) an `std::ostream` object as one of its fields.

All I want to do is to overload the `<<` operator, so I can use this wrapper like a normal stream.
My first idea was just to write it as a function template.

Example:

```cpp
class stream_wrapper
{
    std::ostream& stream;

    template<typename Output>
    friend stream_wrapper& operator<<(stream_wrapper& s, Output output)

public:
    stream_wrapper(std::ostream& stream) : stream(stream) {}
}

template<typename Output>
stream_wrapper& operator<<(stream_wrapper& s, Output output)
{
    s.stream << output;
    return s;
}
```

The idea was that template will be instantiated fine for all types that `std::ostream`'s `operator<<` works.

This works fine with all usual types, but fails when I attempt to pass some stream manipulator, such as `std::endl`.

Example:

```cpp
int main()
{
    stream_wrapper s(std::cout);
    int a = 1;
    double b = 5;
    s << a << ' ' << b << '\n'; // WORKS
    s << std::endl; // DOESN'T COMPILE
}
```

This fails, because the compiler can't deduce the type of `std::endl`.

So, my questions are:

1. Is there a way to make it work?
2. What type things like `std::endl` are?

Thank you!

Comment: `endl` is a [function template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl) . There's an overload of `ostream::operator<<` that takes function pointers (overloads (11) and (12) [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt)); this is what makes `std::cout <<  std::endl` work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, your overloaded `operator<<` is missing a `return *this;` statement.

Second, I/O manipulators are implemented as functions that take a stream object as input. For example, [`std::endl`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl) is declared like this:

```cpp
template< class CharT, class Traits >
std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& endl( std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& os );
```

`std::basic_ostream` has an [overloaded `operator<<`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) which accepts such a function:

```cpp
basic_ostream& operator<<(
    std::basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>& (*func)(std::basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>&) );
```

This overload of `std::basic_ostream::operator<<` will call the `func()` with `*this` as the input parameter, eg:

```cpp
basic_ostream& operator<<(
    std::basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>& (*func)(std::basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>&) )
{
    return func(*this);
}
```

This mechanism is what allows `std::endl` (and other manipulators) to be used with any `std::ostream` object via `operator<<`.

So, in your example, `s << std::endl` does not compile because `std::endl` is expecting a `std::ostream` object, not a `stream_wrapper` object.

To fix this in your wrapper, you will have to add extra overloads of `operator<<` to handle the various kinds of I/O manipulators that are available, eg:

```cpp
class stream_wrapper
{
    std::ostream& stream;

    template<typename Output>
    friend stream_wrapper& operator<<(stream_wrapper&, const Output &);

    friend stream_wrapper& operator<<(stream_wrapper&, std::ios_base& (*)(std::ios_base&) );

    friend stream_wrapper& operator<<(stream_wrapper&, std::ios& (*)(std::ios&) );

    friend stream_wrapper& operator<<(stream_wrapper&, std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&) );

public:
    stream_wrapper(std::ostream& stream) : stream(stream) {}
}

template<typename Output>
stream_wrapper& operator<<(stream_wrapper& s, const Output &output)
{
    s.stream << output;
    return *this;
}

stream_wrapper& operator<<(stream_wrapper& s, std::ios_base& (*func)(std::ios_base&) )
{
    s.stream << func;
    // or: func(s.stream);
    return *this;
}

stream_wrapper& operator<<(stream_wrapper& s, std::ios& (*func)(std::ios&) )
{
    s.stream << func;
    // or: func(s.stream);
    return *this;
}

stream_wrapper& operator<<(stream_wrapper& s, std::ostream& (*func)(std::ostream&) )
{
    s.stream << func;
    // or: func(s.stream);
    return *this;
}
```